# how do i run commands/open-terminal inside Parse standalone container

Tags: docker, parse-platform

I'm running a container of the official docker image **parseplatform/parse-server** :

tried the following but "bash" is not recognized:

```
docker exec -i -t container_name bash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
sudo docker exec -i -t container_name sh
```